# Is there a difference in HDMI cables

Tags: hdmi, cable

I have a single HDMI cable in my house which I seem to be able to use for all my devices (TV, HP PC, Dell PC, PS3, PS4). All my other cables seem to be selective on the device I can connect them with.

My main problem is my office monitors. If I connect the HDMI one to my (work) Dell PC with Windows, it does not work. If I connect it to my (private) HP with Linux, it does work. If I just exchange the cable with my 'wonder' cable it works with both PCs.

Any idea how I resolve this? I just bought new cables for this but it does not seem to help. I bought the ones with the gold connectors and 3D and ethernet support.

Comment: Cables are only categorized into “High Speed” and “Basic”. Of course there are optional features like Ethernet, but I’ve never seen anyone using that. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, no. A spec-compliant HDMI cable is a spec-compliant HDMI cable. With digital signals, it's either perfect image or no image at all, so there's really no reason to shell out for anything more than the $1/ft cables or so.

Comment: Thats what I though! I really dont understand why only one of my cables seem to be able to cope with DELL <-> Samsung

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar situation in the past.

What I find is that sometimes 'branded' HDMI cables are sometimes selective due to working with specific manufacturers devices.

I found that if you purchase an unbranded HDMI cable it will be more likely be usable with multiple devices.

Comment: My cable is not branded :(

Answer (score -1):

The HDMI difference is the version number:

> HDMI devices are manufactured to adhere to various versions of the specification, in which each version is given a number and/or letter, such as 1.0, 1.2, or 1.4b. Each subsequent version of the specification uses the same kind of cable but increases the bandwidth and/or capabilities of what can be transmitted over the cable. A product listed as having an HDMI version does not necessarily mean that it will have all of the features that are listed for that version since some HDMI features are optional, such as deep color and xvYCC (which is branded by Sony as "x.v.Color").Note that with the release of the version 1.4 cable, the HDMI Licensing LLC group (which oversees the HDMI standard) will require that any reference to version numbers be removed from all packaging and advertising for the cable. Non-cable HDMI products starting on January 1, 2012 will no longer be allowed to reference the HDMI number and will be required to state which features of the HDMI specification the product supports.

[Wikipedia HDMI Versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Versions)

So, if you buy 1.4 you can't have any issue. If use a pair of them with TV, Raspberry, ISP TV, laptop...

Comment: That’s no longer relevant either. Since you linked to Wikipedia, you might as well read the section on [cables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Cables): _Category 1 HDMI cables are marketed as "Standard" and Category 2 HDMI cables as "High Speed". This labeling guideline for HDMI cables went into effect on October 17, 2008._ So, no versions there. Also, they’re all compatible.

Comment: I guess I will check the version of my cables anyway, maybe it gives me a hint. I wonder if I can find that out without the box they came with :S

Comment: Found the box of a cable that does not work: HDMI 1.4 High Speed with ethernet. Cant get any better than that. The one that does work I have no clue what it is.

Comment: Does that cable work with any device?

Comment: Yep. Works perfectly fine with the hp (ubuntu) laptop, but not with the dell (win7) laptop.

Comment: And have you got a cable that works with Dell laptop? Maybe is laptop issue... are you pressing Windows+P to go across all monitor modes (Solo, duplicate, only ext.)?